# Paypal redirect after payment transaction coding

Tags: php, redirect, paypal

I have created a site for a business venture and am trying to create a thank you page to redirect after payment is completed. I know how to set up the redirect through PayPal. However, I am not sure of the coding to put on the thank you page to show the customer the items purchased etc.  I have been searching for awhile for this and the best I have come up with is the following:

```
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
```

However, how do I integrate this? Do I just put simple HTML coding for the name of the company before it etc?

Comment: What you are looking for is Paypal's `IPN`, see this for more info and source code https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/#listener

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with paypal integration but after few searching for solution to your problem i came up with this answer
You may need this field in your html parameters

```
<input type='hidden' name='rm' value='2'>
```

And set **`return`** parameter for return url.
And forward it with your php configuration for paypal API or you may set this field directly in your PHP code.

For more information you can refer to following link
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/